# How parsing of dictionary in python works?

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

I have below template.yaml file:

```
Resources:
  ApiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    Properties:
      RestApiId: ApiGateway
```

When I am trying to parse it using below python code:

```
import pathlib
import yaml


def main():
    template_file = pathlib.Path('template.yaml')
    cfn = yaml.safe_load(template_file.read_text())
    for res in cfn["Resources"]:
        print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am getting key as output:

```
ApiGatewayDeployment
```

But when I am parsing it using below code:

```
import pathlib
import yaml


def main():
    template_file = pathlib.Path('template.yaml')
    cfn = yaml.safe_load(template_file.read_text())
    for res in cfn["Resources"],:
        print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am getting dictionary as output:

```
{'ApiGatewayDeployment': {'Type': 'AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment', 'Properties': {'RestApiId': 'ApiGateway'}}}
```

Can anyone please explain this logic?

Edit: updated 2nd python code

Comment: Thanks @iain-shelvington for pointing. I have updated it. the difference in output is just because of a comma(,) in for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with how the dictionary is parsed, but rather the way that you're trying to iterate over its contents.  The difference is a single comma:

```
for res in cfn["Resources"]:
```

vs:

```
for res in cfn["Resources"],:
```

Adding a trailing comma to an expression turns it into a tuple (i.e. it  adds another level of container to it).

In the first version, `res` is iterating over the keys of `cfn["Resources"]`.  (Note: you might want to iterate over `cfn["Resources"].values()` instead!)

In the second version, `res` is iterating over a tuple that contains `cfn["Resources"]` itself.

Hence:

```
    for res in cfn["Resources"],:
        print(res)
```

is exactly equivalent to just doing:

```
    print(cfn["Resources"])
```

Here's a simpler example using a regular old list:

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in arr:
...     print(i)
...
1
2
3
>>> for i in arr,:  # note the comma!
...     print(i)
...
[1, 2, 3]
```